# Can we write pure native mobile app that on blockchain

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, mobile-wallet

I have a web-based blockchain application. On web, I can use metamask for making transaction. On mobile, I can use some Dapp browser such as Toshi ...

But I want to write a native application (pure android/ios application). Do we have any solutions for this. I have searched but don't found any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at [status.im](https://status.im/)

Also, you can use [react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) and include [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) that connects to [infura](https://infura.io/)

Comment: Yes. connect to infura is easy. But how about send transaction (that need username/password), sign transaction ... we often shouldn't do that but through some application (i.e: Metamask on web)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we have mobile application like Metamask on Chrome. (except using some browser such as Trust, Toshi)